# How to wrap a WCF client in a shared library

Tags: c#, wcf

I wrote a WCF service that exposed the following method:

```
byte[] convertToPDF(byte[] fileToConvert)
```

Now I want to create a shared library to wrap that method e.g.

```
List<stream> convertToPDF(List<stream> filesToConvert)

List<string> convertToPDF(List<string> filePathsToConvert)
```

I am able to build a simple client using the svcutil.exe program and run this client from a Console app.  However using the same code fails when I call the constructor in a shared library.

```
public class Client
{
    private DocToPDF client; 

    public Client()
    {
        client = new DocToPDFClient();  // I fail here          
    }
}
```

Here's the Exception:

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IDocToPDF' in the 
ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file 
was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract 
could be found in the client element.
```

This message makes no sense to me because the same code works from a console app but not as a shared library.  Please advise

Comment: You have to propagate endpoints and bindings in the app.config of the shared library that wraps the wcf service calls to whatever app/assembly you are using it from.

Comment: @Jacob sorry haven't had time to test it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WCF you cannot just create an instance of your common class.
You should use "ChannelFactory" instead.

The way you create an instance in WCF (using ChannelFactory) is like this example:

```
ChannelFactoryClient.ServiceReference1.DocToPDF client = ChannelFactory<ChannelFactoryClient.ServiceReference1.DocToPDF>.CreateChannel(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://..."));
```

In WCF you have two options to share your common dll.

1. You can pass "metadata" from the server side to the client side.
   This option would create a proxy class in your client side. The methods you execute on this class would actually execute on the server side (as expected). To use this option you follow [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Using Channel Factory to create the proxy class.
   This option would create a proxy instance on the client side so every method would execute on the server side. (In contrast to your code above which creates an instance and executes it's methods on the client side).

To initialize an instance using ChannelFactory you simply follow [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx).